# R readxl: How to specify the column types of selected columns

Tags: r, readxl

I have an  80 column Excel spreadsheet. I want to read only four of the columns. The position of the columns may change so I would like to select them by column name. I do this by

`df <- read_xlsx("dat")[c("a", "b", "c", "d")]`

However, *d* is guessed incorrectly as a logical while it is in fact a factor with four levels. The type of the columns can be set by `col_type` but the parameters of this function refer to the original 80 columns. Thus, to set the correct type, I would have to know the column position, which I do not. Even if, it seems cumbersome to set 80 column types (probably with `rep()`) although I only need four of them. Reading all as text does not work either because one column is in date:time format which gets scrambled by this.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Packages with java and perl are not working on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

`fread` is in data.table package and will provide the functionality you're looking for.

> Described as the “fast and friendly file finagler”, the popular
>   data.table package is an extremely useful and easy to use. Its fread()
>   function is meant to import data from regular delimited files directly
>   into R, without any detours or nonsense.
>   https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/importing-data-r-part-two

```
df<-fread("path",select=c("col1","col2",..........))
```

Comment: Why should one use that approach? Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: hello,yes with fread function from data.table package can read any type of file

Comment: fread() function is quite useful,it can use to read large dataset in a speedy manner.

Comment: Can you show me a post or a working example where it reads .xlsx files? Because according to other posts, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313025/how-to-load-xlsx-file-using-fread-function, it cannot read xlsx files and google brought up no examples. It also returns an error when I try to read my file with fread().