# data.table::fread Read all worksheets in an Excel workbook

Tags: r, excel, data.table

My Excel document `my.xlsx` has two Sheets named **Sheet1** and **Sheet2**. I want to read all worksheets in an Excel workbook using `fread` function from `data.table` `R` package. The following code just read the active worksheet. Wonder how to read all worksheets without knowing their names. Thanks

```
df3 <- data.table::fread("in2csv my.xlsx")
> names(df3)
[1] "A" "B"
> df3
   A  B
1: 1  2
2: 2  4
3: 3  6
4: 4  8
5: 5 10
```

Comment: Can't you use `readxl` or `openxlsx` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets)

Comment: Yes, I can use `readxl`, `rio` or `openxlsx`. But the size of my actual file is more than **300MB** that's why requires the use of `data.table::fread`. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: It does not have this functionality. I'm not sure if the fread algorithm would be helpful if adapted to do it, but you could look into it by following the instructions here https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52339878/9841389) might be of interest.

Comment: Save your Excel worksheets as CSV files using Excel or Open Office. Then you can trivially use fread.

Comment: @Roland: Not able to open **xlsx** file of size more than **400 MB**.

Comment: @ismirsehregal: I used the same commands.

Comment: So, how were these files created? And what genius decided that this was a good file format for the task?

Comment: Then you may have also seen [this](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/scripts/in2csv.html)? `--write-sheets WRITE_SHEETS The names of the Excel sheets to write to files, or "-" to write all`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used `openxlsx::read.xlsx` the last time I needed to read many sheets from an XLSX.

```
#install.packages("openxlsx")
library(openxlsx)
#?openxlsx::read.xlsx

#using file chooser:
filename <- file.choose()
#or hard coded file name:
#filename <- "filename.xlsx"

#get all the sheet names from the workbook
SheetNames<-getSheetNames(filename)

# loop through each sheet in the workbook
for (i in SheetNames){

  #Read the i'th sheet
  tmp_sheet<-openxlsx::read.xlsx(filename, i)

  #if the input file exists, append the new data;; else use the first sheet to initialize the input file
  ifelse(exists("input"),
         input<-rbind(input, tmp_sheet),
         input<-tmp_sheet)
}
```

Note: This assumes each worksheet has identical column structure and data types. You may need to standardize\normalize the data (ex. `tmp_sheet <- as.data.frame(sapply(tmp_sheet,as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`), or load each sheet into it's own dataframe and pre-process further before merging.

Comment: Thanks @M.Viking for your answer. I wonder if this can read a workbook of size more than **300 MB**.

Comment: The author of openxlsx says  ["Memory issues with Java and xlsx were the reason I wrote this package"](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/73#issuecomment-78234350).  - Have you read the data? Did you get errors?

Comment: Python based command line tool [https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv). "Handles large XLSX files." Note the `-a` argument.

Comment: Thanks @M.Viking for pointing `xlsx2csv`. Would highly appreciate if you provide an  example.

Comment: Check out the second example here https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/methods-convert-xlsx-format-files-csv-linux-cli/ . This is at the command line. On Linux I ran  `$ sudo pip3 install xlsx2csv`, then `$ xlsx2csv -a filename.xlsx foldername` to make a folder with that name and creates one CSV per each sheet. Alternatively `$ xlsx2csv -a filename.xlsx > filename.csv` makes a single CSV, but adds a header row (ex: `-------- sheetname`) between each sheet of data.

Comment: I used `import xlsx2csv` and `xlsx2csv -a my.xlsx foldername` which throws the following error: `File "<stdin>", line 1
    xlsx2csv -a my.xlsx foldername
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the Python interpreter. Run this program at the command\terminal\shell prompt.