# Read xlsx file using data.table::fread(), but selecting the sheet

Tags: r, data.table

I'm not founding any argument in the `fread()` function to let me select the sheet I want.
I'm trying this:

```
tab <- data.table::fread('myfile.xlsx')
```

As my file has many sheets, how can I select just one of them by sheet name?

Answer (score 4):

```
 library("readxl")
 FirstTable  <- read_excel("locations.xlsx", 1) # for first tab
 SecondTable <- read_excel("locations.xlsx", 4) # for fourth tab
```

An alternative way!

You may find this link useful - [importing excel to r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049272/importing-excel-files-into-r-xlsx-or-xls)

Comment: As far as I, and the Internet knows, `fread` can't read Excel files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313025/how-to-load-xlsx-file-using-fread-function

Comment: This is strange, because I can read the xlsx file with `fread()`, however I can't select which sheet I want to use.

Comment: @igorkf can you please upload your xlsx for a test? Because nobody else is able to load an xlsx file aside from you. So we can test it ourselves.

Comment: Sorry, there was a long time ago and I cant reproduce it anymore