# How to use csvkit in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, bigdata, fread, readxl

I have a `.xlsx` file (~70MB) (it's the [2022 National Youth Tobacco Survey data](https://www.cdc.gov/tobacco/data_statistics/surveys/nyts/zip_files/2022/2022-nyts-dataset-codebook-microsoft-excel.zip)) that I'd like to read into R. I am trying to find a faster way than `read_excel` from `readxl` to read the file.

```
> system.time(df <- read_excel("nyts2022.xlsx"))
   user  system elapsed 
  20.25    3.61   70.70
```

From the answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313025/how-to-load-xlsx-file-using-fread-function), it appears that `fread` is more efficient and can convert the file to `.csv` using command line. But I get an error:

```
> df <- fread('in2csv nyts2022.xlsx')
'in2csv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning messages:
1: In (if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") system else shell)(paste0("(",  :
  '(in2csv nyts2022.xlsx) > C:\Users\cloft\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuwQ2G6\file54a06407ad3' execution failed with error code 1
2: In fread("in2csv nyts2022.xlsx") :
  File 'C:\Users\cloft\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuwQ2G6\file54a06407ad3' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
```

How do I go about doing this? I'm a newbie, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly passing to the `cmd` argument of `fread()`? E.g. `fread(cmd = "in2csv nyts2022.xlsx")`

Comment: I tried, I get the same error. Perhaps I have not installed `csvkit`? How do I do it correctly?

Comment: Make sure in2csv is on your PATH.  Another option is to download qsv from https://github.com/jqnatividad/qsv/releases where you can get a standalone binary.  Put it on your PATH and then from within R run `data.table::fread("qsv excel myfile.xlsx")` .

Comment: What is a PATH?

Comment: The PATH is the set of directories where the system looks to find programs.  Assuming that you are on Windows from the cmd line type `PATH` to see it.  You need to put in2csv or qsv in one of those directories or else change your path to include the directory where you put it or else refer to the path to in2csv or qsv in the `fread` command so it knows where to find it.

Comment: Sorry for asking simple questions, I appreciate your patience! How do I get in2csv in the first place, to then put in PATH?